# Create hyperlink to Facebook News Feed preferences

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, facebook

I want to give people a link that they can open and go directly to Facebook's News Feed preferences (which is a lightbox that opens up on top of your current Facebook page).

At the moment, to get there you have to go Facebook -> top RHS dropdown -> News Feed Preferences. The link for News Feed Preferences indicates that Ajax loads the lightbox for News Feed Preferences once you click. I'm not familiar with Ajax so I don't know whether there's a way to append to the Facebook URL to trigger this loading action.

Here's the element in the DOM:

```
<a class="_54nc" href="#" rel="dialog" ajaxify="/feed_preferences/dialog/" data-gt="{&quot;ref&quot;:&quot;async_menu&quot;,&quot;logout_menu_click&quot;:&quot;menu_nf_preferences&quot;}" role="menuitem"><span><span class="_54nh">News Feed Preferences</span></span></a>
```

Comment: Facebook would need to add support in their backend for a URL to lead directly to that popup. There's no way to execute your own code on a page just by adding onto its URL.

Comment: Thanks @JonUleis! Is there any way if e.g. I hosted a link on my own server which somehow took user to Facebook and ran some small script to load News Feed Preferences? Or any other workaround, even if it involves considerable work / resource on my side?

Comment: No workarounds that I know of, even with additional resources. Once you're on another domain, the ball is out of your court.

Comment: Why do you want to link to that?

Comment: @WizKid Specifically: for a feature in a Chrome extension. Generally: because I want to make it easier for people to change their News Feed settings. Telling people to go Facebook -> top RHS dropdown etc. means more complexity + a higher drop-off, means harder to campaign for people to make their News Feeds (now a major time component in many people's lives) a better experience.

Comment: What do you want them to change?

Comment: @WizKid The people and pages they follow.

Comment: There are follow buttons I believe you can use

Comment: @WizKid Agree - the ones on every profile / page / dropdown of a post. But no way to link to News Feed preferences directly? Follow buttons scattered around profiles / pages / dropdowns are of limited usefulness if trying to get people to more actively, and in one place, manage their News Feeds.